# Typedef not being effective in header

Tags: c, header, typedef

I have a C project with a structure as follows:

```
Project
- fileA.h
- fileA.c
+ subdirB
  - fileD.h
```

There is a typedef enum of bool in fileD.h:

```
typedef enum bool {
    false = 0,  /**< false (0) */
    true        /**< true (1) */
} bool;
```

In fileA.c there are several functions that use bool as parameters and so fileD.h is included:

```
#include "subdirB/fileD.h" // header with bool typedef
#include "fileA.h"         // own header with foo declaration
...
int foo (bool bar) {
 ...
 return 0;
}
...
```

These functions are to be made global so their declaration is added to the header fileA.h:

```
int foo (bool bar);
```

This last bit however gives me an error that "the identifier bool is undefined"... I dont understand why this would be the case though??

Comment: Are you getting any warnings when compiling?

Comment: This is beside your question, but just to let you know [C99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) has a boolean - it lives in stdbool.h

Comment: @djf Yes, I know (thanks) I'm working on an embedded platform and creating a lib, need to account for a lib user not having stdbool on platform

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you including `fileD.h` in `fileA.h`? In order to declare a function that takes a bool, the compiler needs to know what a bool is.

Comment: This worked but I dont understand why this is needed, the pattern I described has worked with other types & variables for about 10 other files within the same project...

Comment: I'd have to see those to know what's different. One possibility is that things are getting included that you don't realize. Includes are sort of "viral", in that, if B.h includes A.h, and C.h includes B.h, then C.h has implicitly included A.h. My preferred practice is to explicitly include any and all dependencies so that if you change one include list, you don't break random code elsewhere. Of course, you need to make sure you use include guards.

Comment: My guess is there was something inside that particular header that needed to know about the Boolean type to function.  Either that or in other cases, you had the .h includes accidently in the right order so that this was avoided.

Comment: Thanks guys, I am pretty pedantic about ordering includes and having include guards so that could well be the case. Would it be usual to see a #include inside a header file? I usually have only put the in src files, but I dont know why that is...

Comment: Very common. Have a look at the standard library header files. You can find them online for various *nix distributions, including FreeBSD, for example. Looks like FreeBSD's string.h includes (at least) <sys/cdefs.h>, <sys/_null.h>, and <sys/_types.h>.

Answer (score 1):

As noted earlier, `fileA.h` needs to be aware of the `bool` type defined in `fileD.h` so that the function prototype for `foo()` is valid.

However, note that since your `bool` is not a built-in type, but an `enum`, there is no implicit conversion to `true` for all non-zero values. So do not count on code within `foo()` that looks like:

```
if (bar == true) {
    //...
}
```

to work in the general case. You can alleviate this somewhat with a macro replacement for `foo()`:

```
#define foo(x) foo(!!(x))
```

This becomes tedious if you have many functions that take a `bool`. But the `!!` trick itself works to turn non-zero values into `1` for you though.